# jQuery attribute question

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm trying to select a series of divs one at a time.  I'm sure theres a better way to do this, but I gave them all unique rels and I'm using the rels to select them one at a time.  I want to move them over the width of the div, then animate it dropping down the screen. What I have is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var totalbricks = 7;
        var index = 2;
        $(".brick").animate({top:"600px"});
        while(index < totalbricks)
        {
            var postion = 45*index;
            $(".brick[rel='+index+']").css('left', postion+'px');
            $(".brick[rel='+index+']").animate({top:"600px"});
            index++;
        }
 });
```

All the divs are in a container div.
Jquery docs say, 'Variables can be used using the following syntax: [name='" +MyVar+ "']'
What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is the HTML that is being used by the jQuery

```
    <body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="canvas">
        <div class="brick" rel="1">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="2">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="3">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="4">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="5">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="6">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="7">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you want them all to be animated at the same time, or sequentially?

Comment: Id like it to be sequential.  I was planning on adding a timer in the loop once I got it to animate right to give it a cascading effect.  Mark up is as follows:
 <body>
<div id="container">
 <div id="canvas">
     <div class="brick" rel="1">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="2">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="3">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="4">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="5">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="6">
        </div>
        <div class="brick" rel="7">
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>

</body>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing ' and " in your JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var totalbricks = 7;
            var index = 2;
            $(".brick").animate({top:"600px"});
            while(index < totalbricks)
            {
                    var postion = 45*index;
                    $(".brick[rel="+index+"]").css('left', postion+'px');
                    $(".brick[rel="+index+"]").animate({top:"600px"});
                    index++;
            }
    });
```

Try that notice that in the `.brick[rel=` I used double quotes instead of single quotes.

---

**Update**

You can also do the following, with the `each` function, which may make it easier for you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bricks = $(".bricks");
    bricks.animate({ top: "600px" });

    bricks.find(":not(:first)").each(function(i) {
        var position = 48 * (i + 1);
        $(this).css("left", position + "px");
        $(this).animate({ top: "600px" });
    });
}
```

This is your same method using a more "jQuery" way of accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're looking for [jQuery's each function](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each). I'll edit this with a code sample if/when you post your markup.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, there's just a better way to do it. jQuery provides the each function, which allows you to iterate over all elements that match the inputted selecter.

As luck happens, the example used on the linked page is exactly what you're looking for, just adjust the selecter to your collection of divs. Inside an iteration, the 'this' keyword will represent the DOM element of the current div.

e.g. $("#container_div div").each(...

**References:**
[jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each)

**Edit:** there are two functions in jQuery with the name 'each', although I'm no expert, I believe the one you're looking for is the one I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the .each() that others are suggesting, you might consider using the :gt and :lt selectors for your range. I think you could get rid of the rels and while statement altogether.

```
$(".brick:lt(8):gt(1)).each(function() {
  //$(this) is your brink
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly trying to do in your code...

how about something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.animateTop = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this); <-- this is each one of your bricks
      $this.animate({ top: '600px' });
      ...
   });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.brick').animateTop();
});
```

Comment: This way you return the jQuery object for so you can chain other stuff... for instance you could do something like this:
$('.brick').animateTop().css('border', '1px solid red');